# Variation on the statement: If $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x \in X$ then $\|x\| \leq \liminf \|x_n\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, weak-convergence

I have a question about a proof I'm reading. The statement is:

> Let $X$ be a normed linear space. If $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $x \in X$ then $\|x\| \leq \liminf \|x_n\|$.

The proof is given as follows:
[image]

My questions:

1. Could I have equivalently taken $\limsup$ on both sides to conclude $\|x\| \leq \limsup \|x_n\|$? Indeed the first exercise in the section asks the reader to make an analogous argument:
   [image]
2. If this is so for #1, why is the $\liminf$ result preferable for $\|x\|$ but the $\limsup$ result preferable for $\|\psi\|$?

Comment: You can have $\liminf$ also in the exercise.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo, in 18, and "inf" was meant.

Comment: @DavidMitra I believe so. From $\|\psi\|\le \limsup\|\psi_n\|$ it is easy to get $ \|\psi\|\le \liminf\|\psi_n\|$ by restricting to an appropriate subsequence $\psi_{n_k}.$